# Delete specific file types from Azure Blob Storage in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, delete-file

My pipeline contains Copy data from File System to Blob storage. There are 2 file types which are .jpeg and .json. I would like to put them in separate folder in Blob storage in order to manage them later. Therefore, I have 2 copy activities:

[image: del1]

- Copy json files, this one has no issue as it will only copy json file type
- Copy binary file type, I need to use binary as the type type I want to copy is jpeg. For this activity, after I copy to blob folder, I add Delete activity after to try to delete json files in this folder.

The source for Delete activity is location of the folder in blob that I just copied the binary into. Then, I specified to take only JSON files (*.json) like this:

[image: del2]

My pipeline ran successfully. However, no files were deleted from this location in blob. Could you please let me know what I did wrong? Or if you have a better idea to manage these files differently, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the json file in source after the json was been copied to sink?

Comment: @Bowman Zhu yes exactly, because my copy data activity specified source file type as binary since its the only way to copy jpeg files, therefore there are also json files being copied as well. And; I want to delete them after being copied.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I need to add *.json as Wildcard filename for Source of the Delete activity.

[image: del3]